# Load content into div with Jquery and spring returns 400 bad request message

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am puzzled, I have a call with jQuery using .load to fill a DIV with content composed of transformed XML into HTML, but whenever I call load (or $.get or $.ajax for that matter) I get a "400 Bad Request - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" message.

The parameters are all there and even when I set up a test call for a page with no parameters I get the same message.  All this is being done via Spring (v3) with an annotated controller.  What's confusing is that I already have a portion of this working with calls to a web service that return a JSON object to fill a SELECT and that works fine.

How do I fill the DIV with HTML?

Javascript jQuery call:

```
        function doSearch()
        {
           var sUrl = "query.html";
           var sSecurityToken = '?st=' + $('#ihSecurityToken').val();

           var sProjects = '';
           $("#sltProjects option:selected").each(function () 
              {
                 sProjects += $(this).val() + ';';
              });
           sProjects = '&pn=' + escape(sProjects);

           var sDatabases = '';
           $("#sltDatabases option:selected").each(function () 
              {
                 sDatabases += $(this).val() + ';';
              });
           sDatabases = '&db=' + escape(sDatabases);

           var sQueryText = '&qt=' + escape($('#taSearchText').val());

           sSort = '&sr=' + $('#sltSort').val();
           sResultsPerPage = '&rp=' + $('#sltResultsPerPage').val();
           sRelevance = '&rl=' + $('#sltRelevance').val();

           var sFilters = '&ft=';
           var sTemp = '';
           $("[id^=fld]").each( function() 
              {
                 sName = $(this).attr('alt');
                 sValue = escape($(this).val());
                 sTemp += escape((sName + '=' + sValue + ';'));
              });

           if (sTemp.length)
           {
              sFilters += sTemp;
           }
           else
           {
              sFilters = '';
           }

           var sStartingPage = "&sp=1";


           sFinal = sUrl + sSecurityToken + sProjects + sDatabases + sQueryText + sSort + sResultsPerPage + sRelevance + sFilters + sStartingPage;
           $('#resultsBlock').load(sFinal);
}
```

Controller code:
    package enterprisesearch.web;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import enterprisesearch.domain.DatabaseFilter;
import enterprisesearch.domain.UserDatabaseProject;
import enterprisesearch.domain.service.DouglasService;
/**
 * @author bob
 *
 */
@Controller
public class SearchController
{
   protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

   private DouglasService dgWebService = new DouglasService("http://localhost:8080/Douglas/services/Douglas");

   @RequestMapping("/search.html")
   @ModelAttribute("message")
   public String getMessage()
   {
      return "Results go here...";
   }

   @ModelAttribute("username")
   public String getUsername(@RequestParam(value="username", required=true) String psUsername)
   {
      return psUsername; 
   }

   @ModelAttribute("securitytoken")
   public String getSecurityToken(@RequestParam(value="username", required=true) String psUsername)
   {
      String sReturn = "";
      Map<String, String> mpResult = this.dgWebService.getSecurityToken(psUsername);

      if (mpResult.containsValue("SUCCESS"))
      {
         sReturn = mpResult.get("securityinfo");
      }
      else
      {
         sReturn = mpResult.get("errorid");
      }

      return sReturn;
   }

   @ModelAttribute("userprojects")
   public Collection<UserDatabaseProject> getUserProjects(@RequestParam(value="username", required=true) String psUsername) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
   {
      String sUsername = "";
      if (psUsername == null || psUsername.isEmpty())
      {
         sUsername = "lymana";
      }
      else
      {
         sUsername = psUsername;
      }
      return this.dgWebService.getUserDatabaseProjects(sUsername);
   }

   @RequestMapping("/databases.html")
   public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> getUserDatabases(@RequestParam(value="username", required=true) String psUsername, @RequestParam(value="projectname", required=true) String psProjectName) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
   {
      Map<String, String> mpDatabases = new HashMap<String, String>();

      Collection<UserDatabaseProject> udpProjects = this.dgWebService.getUserDatabaseProjects(psUsername);
      if (udpProjects.size() > 0)
      {
         for (UserDatabaseProject udpProject : udpProjects)
         {
            if (psProjectName.indexOf(udpProject.get_msProjectName()) != -1)
            {
               mpDatabases.put(udpProject.get_msDatabaseName(), udpProject.get_msDatabaseDescription());
            }
         }
      }
      else
      {
         mpDatabases.put("","No databases were found for the selected project");
      }

      return mpDatabases;
   }

   @RequestMapping("/filters.html")
   public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> getCommonDBFilters(@RequestParam(value="databases", required=true) String psDatabaseNames) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
   {
      Map<String, String> mpDatabases = new HashMap<String, String>();

      Collection<DatabaseFilter> dfFilters = this.dgWebService.getCommonDBFilters(psDatabaseNames);
      if (dfFilters.size() > 0)
      {
         for (DatabaseFilter dfFilter : dfFilters)
         {
            if (psDatabaseNames.indexOf(dfFilter.get_msDatabaseName()) != -1)
            {
               mpDatabases.put(dfFilter.get_msFilterName(), dfFilter.get_msFilterName());
            }
         }
      }
      else
      {
         mpDatabases.put("","No filters were found for the selected database(s)");
      }

      return mpDatabases;
   }


   @RequestMapping("/test.html")
   public ModelAndView execTest()
   {
      //Map<String, String> mpDatabases = new HashMap<String, String>();
      ModelAndView mavReturn = new ModelAndView("test.jsp");
      //mpDatabases.put("test","<b>No filters were found for the selected database(s)</b>");

      return mavReturn;
   }

   //@ModelAttribute("searchResults")
/*   @RequestMapping(value = "/query.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView doSearch(@RequestParam(value="st", required=true) String psSecurityToken,
         @RequestParam(value="pn", required=true) String psProjects,
         @RequestParam(value="db", required=true) String psDatabases,
         @RequestParam(value="qt", required=true) String psQueryText,
         @RequestParam(value="sr", required=true) String psSort,
         @RequestParam(value="rp", required=true) String psResultsPerPage,
         @RequestParam(value="rl", required=true) String psRelevance,
         @RequestParam(value="sp", required=true) String psStartingPage,
         @RequestParam(value="ft", required=false) String psFilters)
   {
      ModelAndView mavReturn = new ModelAndView("query.jsp");
      String sTemp = "";
      String sOptions = "";
      String sStartingPage = "1";
      if (!psStartingPage.isEmpty())
      {
         sStartingPage = psStartingPage;
      }

      String sSort = "Sort=" + psSort;
      String sResultsPerPage = "ResultsStart=" + sStartingPage + ";ResultsEnd=" + psResultsPerPage;
      String sDatabases = "Repositories=" + psDatabases.replace(';', ',');
      String sRelevance = "RelevanceMin=" + psRelevance;
      String sDefaults = "Print=All;SummaryType=Context;Highlighting=Terms+SummaryTerms;";
      sOptions = sSort + ";" + sResultsPerPage + ";" + sDatabases + ";" + sRelevance + ";" + sDefaults;

      //sReturn = this.dgWebService.executeTextQuery(psSecurityToken, psProjects, psDatabases, psQueryText, sOptions, psFilters);
      sTemp = "<b>This is a test</b>";
      mavReturn.addObject("searchResults", sTemp);
      return mavReturn;
   }*/

   /*@RequestMapping(value = "/test.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView doTest(@RequestParam(value="st", required=true) String psSecurityToken)
   {
      String sTemp = "";
      ModelAndView mavReturn = new ModelAndView("test.jsp");

      //sReturn = this.dgWebService.executeTextQuery(psSecurityToken, psProjects, psDatabases, psQueryText, sOptions, psFilters);
      sTemp = "<b>This is a test</b>";
      mavReturn.addObject("searchResults", sTemp);
      return mavReturn;
   }*/


}
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:8085/EnterpriseSearch/query.html?st=kjahsdf9845hasfha9348uwhefas&pn=ECC%3B&db=dbECC%3B&qt=money&sr=relevance&rp=10&rl=90&sp=1&ft=false
```

Firebug info:

```
Response Headersview source
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length  971
Date    Thu, 03 Nov 2011 20:06:56 GMT
Connection  close
Request Headersview source
Host    localhost:8085
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.23) Gecko/20110920             Firefox/3.6.23
Accept  text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost:8085/EnterpriseSearch/search.html?username=lymana
Cookie  JSESSIONID=CC30B029E8C9215489D4F938A6C1BB9D
```

Any ideas?  What am I missing?

Updated to include the complete Controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and pasted your Java code into my Spring 3.0 testing application, and hit that URL manually.  If you hit that URL directly, do you get the same 400?

There are a few simple problems I could see happening, but you've most likely already ruled them out.. I just don't have enough info reading your message to know!

1. Do you have a view that matches the string that you're returning from the RequestMapped function?
2. Is it even calling that doSearch function(), if you add a trace message to it?
3. Is there anything at all in your error logs?
4. What does your access log say?

Comment: If I hit the URL manually I get the same error.
Hmm... do I have a query.jsp file?  No.  Didn't think I needed one.  Sry Spring / JSP is new for me.
It is calling the doSearch function and nothing appears in the logs

Comment: So, it is calling that function?  I use Spring with Freemarker, so I'm not 100% sure how you're working with JSP, but the return value from a String controller function is supposed to be the name of the template that you're displaying to the user (or in your case, AJAXing in)

Comment: If you look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html
A String value which is interpreted as view name, with the model implicitly determined through command objects and ModelAttribute annotated reference data accessor methods. The handler method may also programmatically enrich the model by declaring a ModelMap argument (see above).

Comment: It just looks to me like you're trying to return AJAX text in the String return value, and that's not how Spring controllers work.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do.  So what do I do then?  I'm new to this and am under the gun to make this work (i.e. I don't have a lot of time) so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok I've read through the Spring Docs and created a test page (test.jsp).  It takes nothing and has a ModelAttribute whereby a message is inserted into the content of a DIV.  Added the RequestMapping to the Controller to fill an attribute on the page named ${message}.  Finally I added the following to doSearch `alert("Made it here!");
               $('#resultsBlock').load('test.html #test');`  and I still get 400 Bad Request
`@RequestMapping("/test.html")
   @ModelAttribute("message")
   public String getTest()
   {
      return "<b>This is a test</b>";
   }`

Comment: The way all of the pages I've written work is we do:
    `@RequestMapping(value = "/query.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)`
    `public ModelAndView doSearch(@RequestParam(...)) {`
      ... build your string ...
      `ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("your/jsp/here");`
      `mav.addObject("result", yourString);`
      `return mav;`
    `}`

And then in your jsp file, have the ${result} variable in it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: No dice.  I'm starting to think there's something else that's buggering up the works.  I tried a simple method whereby I wanted to return a JSON object like my two select boxes (which work BTW) and still get a 400 Bad request error.  Can't figure this one out.

Comment: Have you tried using a ResponseEntity?  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

    `public ResponseEntity<String> doSearch() {`
        `HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();`
        `headers.setContentType(new MediaType("text", "javascript", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));`
        `return new ResponseEntity<String>(yourString, headers, HttpStatus.OK);`
    `}`

Sorry, I'm starting to reach here!

Comment: Well that didn't work either.  I've tried everything I can think of and to no avail.  Even a simple `@RequestMapping("/test.html")
   public ModelAndView execTest()
   {
      ModelAndView mavReturn = new ModelAndView("test.jsp");

      return mavReturn;
   }`  fails with the same error.  What's puzzling is that it works for the two JSON calls to populate a pair of select boxes.

Comment: In interesting behavior I noticed is that when I click on either one of the multi-select controls, it triggers the methods which populate the attribute fill with the controller.  When I click the button to perform the search it doesn't trigger them at all.

Comment: The strangest thing to me is that nothing is showing up in your error logs.  I'm wondering what could be happening to cause that.  Do you have your log level set really high, so it might be eating error messages?

Comment: Ok, figured it out.  Wow, one missing required parameter and a change to the log level and now it works.  Wondering though why it re-processes all the other methods when they don't apply to that request mapping.  When I call test.html all the attribute methods get called.  Is there a way to stop this?  BTW Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hooray!  I'm glad you got it working!  If your problem's solved, can you mark this as accepted, even if I didn't solve your problem with the initial answer? =)  
And as to test.html, I'm not sure what you mean by all of the attribute methods getting called.  Do you mean multiple controller methods are getting hit for the same URL?

Comment: Will do on the accepted request.  You didn't solve it directly, but you pointed me in the right direction which is just as good in my book.  Yes, if I call test.html then getMessage(), getUsername(), etc all get called.  Not sure why that happens though.

Comment: Ahh, yeah. ModelAttribute functions are always called, and they're called before RequestMapping functions.open http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib